# OverDue Custom Task is firing when it shouldn't

Tags: designer-workflow

This Workflow is running and sending the "Overdue" email even when the % Complete field for the item is 100.

Can you tell me how my logic is incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave's answer sounds right, I haven't verified either. Another option would be to say If Current Item Status in not equal to Complete -> Send Email.

Answer (score 2):

100% is often treated as 1, so 50% would be 0.5.  I am not certain that is your issue in this case but worth a look?